# Authenticating USER from a remote database through WSDL

Tags: html, oracle, web-services, wsdl

I have a webpage in which i have login form. It takes EMP No(username) and ADS Password (password) from the user and then authenticates it. The Web Service returns
'Y' on Success & 'N' on Failure.

I don't have direct access to database. Instead, i have been provided with a WSDL.

I need to consume this WS to authenticate users through ADS.

I have no idea how to do this as this is the first time i'm doing this.

I want to know how to achieve this.

PS: The database is ORACLE